Why does my Telegram Login Widget validation not work?
Telegram login widget returns something like this:
.../callback?id=1234567890&first_name=xxx&username=xxx&photo_url=urlhere&auth_date=1234567890&hash=verylonghashhere

toDateCheckString() will return:
id=1234567890\nfirst_name=xxx\nusername=xxx\nphoto_url=urlhere\nauth_date=1234567890\nhash=verylonghashhere

However, I cannot generate the same hash I got from Telegram. I don't get what's wrong, I followed the guide and compared my code with their official php example.
private toDataCheckString(): string {
    const sortedEntries = Object.entries(this)
        .filter(([key, value]) => typeof value !== "function" && key !== "hash" && value !== undefined)
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    const dataCheckString = sortedEntries
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
        .join("\n");
    return dataCheckString;
}

validate(bot_token: string): void {
    const dataCheckString = this.toDataCheckString();
    console.log(dataCheckString);
    const secret_key = createHmac("SHA256", "WebAppData").update(bot_token).digest();
    const expectedHash = createHmac("SHA256", secret_key).update(dataCheckString).digest("hex");
    console.log(this.hash);
    console.log(expectedHash);
    if (this.hash !== expectedHash) {
        throw new HttpException("Invalid hash in the provided telegram callback.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

I've suspected some values from the uri are not supposed to be included when converting with toDataCheckString(), tried disabling and enabling them one by one. Not working.
note: I'm filtering out the undefined and functions too since it's a dto and I have some functions built there, while they should not be included in the dataCheckString.
another note: from their official code it seems like "hashs" field should not be included when creating dataCheckString
